# Microsoft.SPOT doesnt work in a winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, netduino

I have a problem with my winform project.For a project I have a netduino and I made a class for the connection with the netduino. When I was done with that I made a winform project so when I pressed a button on the application the LED on the netduino turned on.

So now to the problem.

I tried to run the application but it gave a error.

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'SPOT' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

How can i fix it so that it works with the windows form application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc506546.aspx

The namespace is in .NET Micro Framework. Thus, you cannot use it in WinForms applications.

To connect to netduino and manipulate its hardware, your WinForms app should use a communication channel opened to the app running on netduino, such as via USB,

http://blog.mark-stevens.co.uk/2011/05/windows-application-communicating-with-netduino-over-usb/